# CSS Only Accordion Table won't toggle properly

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, html-table

I have a table where I have created an accordion-like effect on it using CSS only (no jQuery). The accordion effect is working,  however it only works if I click on the checkboxes as seen on this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/55nk6s4q/

(I deliberately didn't hide the checkboxes in the fiddle so anyone can test it).

As you can see in the code, I have nested tables. If you click on the original row:

```
<tr for="row1">
   <td class="closed">+</td>
   <td>123</td>
   <td>John</td>
   <td>Doe</td>
   <td>02-15-1982</td>
  <td>M</td>
</tr>
```

You'd get the other tables that have a class name of `employee-info` underneath that row, like an accordion.

The only way I was able to get `row2` to collapse and work like an accordion was to make it a separate table and giving the table the same name as the original one:

```
<table class="table-bordered table-responsive employee accordion-row" for="row2">
```

Otherwise, the accordion effect would not work even if I placed the `for="row2` inside the `<tr>` element. As a result, the style of that row doesn't align with the original table. To toggle that row (`row2`) I can only get it by checking the second checkbox and not by clicking on the plus sign (+) as it was intended.

My question is, how can I get these components to toggle by clicking on the row from the original table and not have to click on the checkbox everytime?

Comment: Note that `<tr>` is the only thing that can be a direct child of `<table>`. Placing an input there is invalid HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Note:** This can be done with CSS, but should be done with javascript. This is a fun experiment, **which works**, but it is not recommended for production use.

- Rearrange the HTML so that the dropdown table is located in its own row, spanning all the columns with its single cells `colspan` attribute:

  ```
  <tr><td colspan="6"><table></table></td></tr>
  ```
- Place the checkbox input before the nested table. It can be triggered with a label placed in each rows first cell, like so:

  ```
  <td><label for="row1"></label>123</td>
  ```
- We can position the label over the entire row with absolute positioning and some z-index to place it on top:

  ```
  label {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     width: 1000px;
     z-index: 2;
  }
  ```

  The width has to be absurdly wide enough so that the entire row is covered. It is positioned relative to its parent `td` and cut off with `overflow: hidden` on the table.

  Now the entire row is clickable:

  [image: Screenshot]

#### Example

In IE, the borders are a little bit messed up. This requires a little bit of tweaking.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  overflow: hidden;
}
table table {
  display: none;
  margin: 10px;
}
input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + table {
  display: table;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
}
label {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 1000px;
  z-index: 2;
}
label:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.2);
}
table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2n) > td {
  padding: 0;
}
table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2n) > td td {
  padding: 5px;
}
th,
td {
  border: solid 1px #000;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>DOB</th>
      <th>Gender</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label for="row1"></label>
        123
      </td>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>02-15-1982</td>
      <td>M</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="6">
        <input id="row1" type="checkbox">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>Phone Number</th>
            <td>555-3226</td>
            <th>City:</th>
            <td>New York</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Hire Date:</th>
            <td>8/13/12</td>
            <th>Salary:</th>
            <td>$48,000</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label for="row2"></label>
        123
      </td>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>02-15-1982</td>
      <td>M</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="6">
        <input id="row2" type="checkbox">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>Phone Number</th>
            <td>555-3226</td>
            <th>City:</th>
            <td>New York</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Hire Date:</th>
            <td>8/13/12</td>
            <th>Salary:</th>
            <td>$48,000</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This works like a charm! Thank you so much for your help. And yes, I think it's much easier to do this in JavaScript: I had done it using jQuery before, but I was told that in this case, CSS is better for performance. Once again, thanks for your help.